# Fix .map is not a function in a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I have a Textbox where I set array items to the textbox and I use it as a drop down. My code works and I am able to see the items in the drop down, however when i click on any other item apart from the first item I get the error groups.map is not a function.
I set array from the API to my groups and then I try to map the items that I need into the textbox.
Please see my code below and assist me to fix it.

**I set my state to an empty array here**

```
const [groups, setGroups] = useState([]);

const handleChange = event => {
setGroups({
  ...groups,
  [event.target.name]: event.target.value
});
};
```

**I handle my API call here**

```
axios
  .post('http://', formData, config)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
    setGroups(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.response);
  });
}, []);
```

**I render  with my data to show in the drop down here**

```
          <TextField
              fullWidth
              label="Select Group"
              margin="dense"
              name="groups"
              onChange={handleChange}
              required
              select
              // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-sort-props
              SelectProps={{ native: true }}
              value={groups.name}
              variant="outlined"
            >
              {groups.map(option => (
                <option
                  key={option.id}
                >
                  {option.name}
                </option>
              ))}
            </TextField>
```

Comment: You've used `groups.name` as the value. Is `groups` an object?

Comment: groups would have to be an Array to have a map method

Comment: Yes groups is an array. I will update my question shortly with how I set my groups to an array data from the api.

Comment: Aren't you setting `groups` to an object in the `handleChange` function?

Comment: Hello @soulLess That is exactly what I am doing. Please check my codes.

Comment: Yes, so it's no longer an array, it's an object, and that's why .map fails.

Comment: Why don't you set a different variable for `value` of `TextField` in the `handleChange` function instead of converting `groups` to an object and using `groups.name`?

Comment: @soulLess will appreciate it if you can show me how to with some codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a new state variable to store the selected group.

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState();
```

Your handleChange function will become something like

```
const handleChange = event => {
  setSelected(event.target.value);
};
```

And your TextField component will have it's value changed to match the corresponding state variable:

```
            <TextField
              fullWidth
              label="Select Group"
              margin="dense"
              name="groups"
              onChange={handleChange}
              required
              select
              // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-sort-props
              SelectProps={{ native: true }}
              value={selected}
              variant="outlined"
            >
              {groups.map(option => (
                <option
                  key={option.id}
                >
                  {option.name}
                </option>
              ))}
            </TextField>
```

Comment: Great and detailed explanation. Thank you very much for assisting me. So I was setting the group again to an object when there is a change on the TextField an that is what makes .map method fail. Thanks so much.

Comment: Cool, no problem :)

Answer (score 2):

It is because axios is not done with the request and your state has not been updated yet when you try to map over your state. Try this piece of code near the map:

```
{groups && groups.map(option => (
     <option
      key={option.id}
     >
       {option.name}
     </option>
 ))}
```

The map will go over the array only if `groups` exists

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem look for response that you are getting if it is an object you can convert it to array in api by

```js
Object.entries(images)
```

Then send this response also in client side when you request data set data with res.data otherwise it will be huge object.....